# Autohotkey - ControlClick inside window

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following ahk script to run C&C Generals:

```
#SingleInstance ignore
CoordMode, Mouse, Relative

Run C:\Users\william\Desktop\Generals.lnk

a::Left
s::Down
d::Right
w::Up

Loop{
sleep, 500
}
Until WinExist("ahk_exe Generals.exe")

sleep, 200
SetControlDelay -1
ControlClick, 1, ahk_class #32770, "", LEFT, 10, 300, 300

Loop{
sleep, 500
}

Until WinExist("ahk_exe Generals.exe")
WinWaitClose
Exit
```

The problem is that I can't get the ControlClick to click the second button.

[image]

I've read the manual but I can't figure out why this is not working. I don't even know if it clicks at all.

Got it working:

```
#SingleInstance ignore
CoordMode, Mouse, Relative

Run C:\Users\william\Desktop\Generals.lnk

winWait, ahk_exe Generals.exe

Click 300, 300

winWait, ahk_exe Generals.exe
WinWaitClose
Exit

a::Left
s::Down
d::Right
w::Up
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

too much to comment on, I'll make it an answer instead:

```
a::Left
s::Down
d::Right
w::Up

Loop{
...
```

Key remappings (`s::Down`) bring a `return` with them implicitly. Same way as a hotkey like `s::msgbox, hi` is only the short form for

```
s::
    msgbox, hi
return
```

, key remappings are only a short form for multiple lines. So, your script terminates already after the `Run` command. Put all your hotkeys, labels, functions, hotstrings and key remappings **after** everything you want to happen on program start. You can see your script behaviour if you double click the task bar icon. For more info, see [the auto-execute section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto).

---

```
loop
    sleep, 500
Until WinExist("ahk_exe Generals.exe")
```

there is actually a special command for this in AutoHotkey:

```
winWait, ahk_exe Generals.exe
```

---

```
ControlClick, 1, ahk_class #32770, "", LEFT, 10, 300, 300
```

controlClick is useful if you want to click into a window which is not in foreground. According to your image, C&C is pretty much in your foreground. So I guess you could simply use the [click](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm) command.

Also (see [controlClick](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm) explanation) the `1` as control-or-pos does not make any sense.. and what do you mean by `300, 300`? These are the *options* and *excludeTitle* parameters

---

```
WinWaitClose
```

do you intend to exit the game with your script? if not, this line makes no sense

---

```
Exit
```

if you want to keep your script running (for using the key remappings), exit is okay but `return` would be more appropriate. If you want to exit the whole script, use `exitapp` instead

---

> The problem is that I can't get the ControlClick to click the second button.

what button??

Comment: With `WinWaitClose` I want to wait until I stop the game and then also stop the script. And I want to click the zero hour button. BTW good tips I shall rewrite my script.